# Two columns with the same alias in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, alias

Why is it allowed to query

```
SELECT 
  'foo' "baz",
  'bar' "baz"
```

in Postgres (tested on 9.6)? In which situations does this make sense? On the first look this just seems like a great source of bugs.

Comment: you are hard coding alias. The query is sound what you call the columns is up to you. This is a 'developer' issue and not really an issue with Postgres.

Comment: It's not a source of bugs if you have to explicitly give it a duplicate alias.

Comment: I believe the trick is to avoid such an approach. Although it's hard for me to imagine, there are certainly use cases that demand such alias duplication. So, PostgreSQL is actually quite flexible to allow it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a user's responsibility for how the data will be presented. There are two typical cases in which a novice should be attentive. The first one concerns *anonymous* columns, e.g.:

```
select 'alfa', 'beta'

 ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------
 alfa     | beta
```

The second one concerns joining tables with the same column names, e.g.

```
select *
from company c
join employee e on company_id = c.id

 id |  name   | id | name  | company_id 
----+---------+----+-------+------------
  1 | Company |  1 | Smith |          1
```

In both cases one should use aliases to make the column names unambiguous and more informative. And I always do this in my queries which can be read by others. However, when I'm querying a database ad hoc I'm sometimes thankful that Postgres is not too restrictive and I don't have to write down several column names instead of asterisk.

Most importantly, Postgres checks whether column names are unique in cases where this is really relevant and never allows data integrity violation, e.g.:

```
create view my_view as 
select 'foo' as "baz", 'bar' as "baz"

ERROR:  column "baz" specified more than once
```

Comment: _However, when I'm querying a database ad hoc I'm sometimes thankful that Postgres is not too restrictive and I don't have to write down several column names instead of asterisk._
This. Thanks, accepted!